# maven-dependency-plugin not excluding matching files

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to get rid of .SF, .DSA and .RSA files from bouncycastle so I can include the jar into my jar and deploy it remotely.  I've found that I need to use maven-dependency-plugin, however the exclusions don't seem to actually...exclude.  Kind of defeats the whole purpose.

If I decompress the file, the signed keys are still in there, specifically in the META-INF directory.  If I manually delete them and re-jar it, the application works.  I just need to figure out how to automatically exclude those files!

Below is my POM file, can anyone see where I'm going wrong and how to fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <!-- Declare Maven plugins -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>**/*.SF</excludes>
                        <excludes>**/*.DSA</excludes>
                        <excludes>**/*.RSA</excludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Set a compiler level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mycom.MyApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<name>MyApp</name>
```

**EDIT 1** Based on a suggestion, I tried specifying all artifacts above the exclusions and it still doesn't work.  When I decompress the jar file, the signed keys are still in it.  Here is my revised POM (snippet).  I have noticed the output from Netbeans during the unpacking phase shows 'Includes "" and excludes "" ' for each package.  How do I configure it to remove the signed key files from the jar?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <!-- Other configuration items -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT 2 - Final answer** I got it to work using Ralf's answer below with the following POM snippet.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.mycom.MyApp</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is the [mave-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) not a better fit for your purpose? Maybe this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274151/apache-camel-packaging-an-executable-jar/21276127#21276127) helps.

Comment: Whomever downvoted the question, care to comment?

Comment: Hi @Ralf, maven-shade-plugin worked!  If you create a simple answer, i'll accept it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the [mave-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) is a better fit for your purposes. It offers several transformers that allow you to control what action to take for certain resources before including them into the final uber-jar.

Have a look at the `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer`.

Maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274151/apache-camel-packaging-an-executable-jar/21276127#21276127) also helps to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<configuration>
    <filters>
        <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
    <!-- Other configuration items -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work.  I modified my question to include the revised snippet.  I noticed in the NB output, it doesn't even show that it's looking to exclude the files, which it was doing initially.